# ios standalone safari app won't play HTML5 audio if ringer on silent

Tags: javascript, ios, audio, mobile-safari, iphone-standalone-web-app

If my iPhone's ringer is on silent, my app will not play HTML5 audio in my standalone mode.  However, in the safari app, it will play just fine.

Is this some setting on my phone?  Can I get around this some how?  Can I detect if the ringer is on silent through JavaScript?

Comment: Thanks, sorry I don't have a solution but i solved my silent homescreen page link, with this question